# Build of Tensorflow 2.0 from source fails on Windows "Could not find bazel-bin"

Tags: tensorflow, build, python-3.7, bazel, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to build Tensorflow 2.0 on Windows to make use of AVX2 support, as the default package from "pip install tensorflow" does not include AVX2 support. I'm following the guide here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows

After a lot of failed builds, I was finally successful in building after setting the environment variables to Visual Studio 2017. The final command, ran from c:\tmp\tensorflow (which took 9 hours to complete) was:

`bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --define=no_tensorflow_py_deps=true`

The next step in the instructions "[Build the package](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#build_the_package)" says to run

`bazel-bin\tensorflow\tools\pip_package\build_pip_package C:/tmp/tensorflow_pkg`

If I do that directly (from c:\tmp\tensorflow), I get the error "The system cannot find the path specified.".

I then looked at the final messages from the build:

> C:/users/john.doe/_bazel_john.doe/3ttaaxce/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.exe
>
> INFO: Elapsed time: 32810.307s, Critical Path: 25586.71s
>
> INFO: 8885 processes: 8885 local.
>
> INFO: Build completed successfully, 11312 total actions

From here it looks like build_pip_package.exe is in a different location, so I ran

`C:/users/john.doe/_bazel_john.doe/3ttaaxce/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package C:/tmp/tensorflow_pkg`

but this resulted in the error:

> Fri Oct 11 08:30:40 PDT 2019 : === Preparing sources in dir: /tmp/tmp.B207TraE5w
>
> Could not find bazel-bin.  Did you run from the root of the build tree?

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by re-compiling from source to a new directory c:\tmp2\tensorflow. This time `build_pip_package.exe` was in the correct location and I was able to successfully build the pip package and install.

Comment: How did you change the path to another folder not relative to the install folder?

Comment: @Andrej - I'm not sure what you mean. I just ran *bazel-bin\tensorflow\tools\pip_package\build_pip_package C:/tmp2/tensorflow_pkg*. The portion **C:/tmp2/tensorflow_pkg** is an absolute path

Comment: I have the exact same problem you described above. My build is complete but bazel compiles it into that Users folder as a link. When I try to run the build_pip_package.exe it doesn't find it (although there). What parameters did you specify in the bazel build command to compile it to another folder?

Comment: @Andrej - have you tried starting from the beginning, re-compiling, and then changing to a new tmp directory? On Github it was suggested that perhaps c:\tmp was being mismanaged (link - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33265).

Comment: Ah ok, so you just changed the directory from where you built. I thought you did something like: "bazel --output_user_root=C:\tmp2 build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package" to change the bazel output directory. But ok I will try that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bazel creates a link from `bazel-bin` to the output directory. This behavior is governed by the `--symlink_prefix` option. Try running bazel with `--announce_rc` and see if that option is set somewhere - it may be creating a link with a different name, or not creating one at all.

Also, whatever program in tensorflow assumes the output will be in `bazel-bin` is mistaken. For node projects we recommend `--symlink_prefix=dist/` so the outputs go in `dist/bin` in your project.